# User's folder missing in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles, regedit

When I turn on my computer, I receive error:

```
We can't sign into your account
```

[image: popup]

- I Logged in with the temporary account and can still open my user's files within `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop`. I followed *Option 1* from [this](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-we-cant-sign-into-your-account-error-on-windows/) solution, but no luck, so I played around with `regedit` by referring to those stated in solution above:

  - ```
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
    ```

    I changed `ProfileImagePath` in `S-1-5-21-2708815971-2449333151-1371584642-1000` from `C:\Users\Temp` to `C:\Users\Admin`
  - The nightmare then began, as I cannot see my files and folders anymore; when I go to `C:\Users` there is no `Admin` folder anymore. I've tried changing back everything I modified to its original values, but nothing good happens *(I know my biggest mistake is I didn't make a backup of it while I still can access them)*

Is there any way I can retrive it back?

Comment: @Ramhound I guess the built-in administrator is the one that I used before. And I've checked every directories in C:\ including hidden files but didn't find any

Comment: Yeah but there is no Administrator folder. and Admin is the only user account in my computer, without password. Tried to browse the directory as you mention but it says _"window can't find..."_

Comment: Once a User Profile has been corrupted, there is no [efficient] way to recover it - due to this, the only solution is to create a new User Profile and migrate data over from the old one

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes this is a once-occur issue *(sign out, sign in again, and everything works fine)*, but if the issue hasn't resolved after re-signing in, try the following methods:

1. Fix the user account profile
2. Log on to Windows and copy your data to a new account
3. Delete the error SID and create a new profile

For detailed information, refer to guide: 
 [You receive a "*The User Profile Service failed the logon*” error message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947215/you-receive-a-the-user-profile-service-failed-the-logon-error-message)

Comment: I've tried sign out and in few dozen times with no luck. And those methods cannot be applied now since I've lost my data

Comment: Microsoft Support Site is really suck

Comment: Once a User Profile has been corrupted, there is no [efficient] way to recover it - due to this, the only solution is to create a new User Profile and migrate data over from the old one

Answer (score -1):

There is no [efficient] way to recover a corrupted User Profile, so the only fix is to create a new User Profile and migrate data over from the old one:

---

[Fix a corrupted user profile in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile-in-windows-1cf41c18-7ce3-12f9-8e1d-95896661c5c9)

1. **Create new user:** <sup>*(either 1.1 or 1.2)*</sup>

   1. **My Computer is on a Domain:** <sup>(create local account)</sup>

      1. Open *Microsoft Management Console*: <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open*: `mmc` → OK
      2. Add snap-in: *Local Users and Groups*

         1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> → Select: *Local Users and Groups* → *Add >* → *Local computer* → *Finish* → *OK*
      3. *Console Root* → *Local Users and Groups (Local)* → *Users*

         1. *Action* → *New User...* → Configure user → *Create* → *Close*
         2. Reboot and sign in with new user
   2. **My Computer is in a Workgroup:** <sup>(create local Admin account)</sup>

      1. <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> → *Settings* → *Accounts* → *Family & other users*
      2. *Other users*: *Add someone else to this PC*

         1. *I don't have this person's sign-in information*
         2. *Add a user without a Microsoft account* → Configure user → *Next*
      3. Change new user to an Administrator account

         1. *Other users* → Select user → *Change account type*
         2. *Account Type*: *Administrator* → *OK*
         3. Reboot and sign in with new user

---

2. **Copy files to new User Profile:** <sup>(logged in as new user)</sup>

   1. Open Admin terminal: <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open*: `powershell` → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+*OK*
   2. Migrate data over via [`RoboCopy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy):

      ```cmd
      # Don't copy hidden system files/directories into the root of %UserProfile%, as doing so will corrupt the User Profile depending on the file [e.g. ntuser.dat]:
        RoboCopy "C:\Users\<old-user>" "$env:UserProfile" /XA:S /XD "AppData" /E /Z /V /ETA /TEE /LOG+:"$env:UserProfile\RoboCopy.log"

      # Copy system files/directories into a subdirectory [Old-System-Files] within %UserProfile%:
        RoboCopy "C:\Users\<old-user>" "$env:UserProfile\Old-System-Files" /IA:S /E /Z /V /ETA /TEE /LOG+:"$env:UserProfile\RoboCopy-SystemFiles.log"
      ```

      1. If needed, manually move *needed* files via Explorer from `%UserProfile%\Old-System-Files` to the default location within `%UserProfile%` *(e.g. applications or files from within `.\Old-System-Files\AppData`, etc.)*
      2. If data is needed from old user's Registry hive [`NTUSER.dat`], manually mount the hive, browse it via `RegEdit`, then unload the hive:

         ```cmd
         # Load hive:
           Reg Load HKU\temp "$env:UserProfile\Old-System-Files\NTUSER.dat"

         # Open Registry Editor and navigate to HKU\temp:
           RegEdit

         # Once done, unload the older user's hive:
           Reg unload HKU\temp
         ```
   3. Reboot and log in as new user

---

3. **Migrate applicable system data from `%UserProfile%\Old-System-Files\AppData`:**

   1. If you have email messages in an email program, you must import your email messages and addresses to the new user profile separately
   2. Some applications previously installed may need to be reconfigured or reinstalled *(see 2.2.1 & 2.2.2)*
   3. If you were logged into Microsoft Store apps like the *Store* or *Movies & TV* you may need to log back into those apps to see your previous purchases and/or restore settings

Comment: my problem during this time was there is no more _"data from the old one"_ as I accidentally delete it .but its ok, I already moved on without those data